# WPF layout changes (Fill, Full, Snapped)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Win8 app destined for the Windows Store. Hurdles I am trying to overcome is how to deal with the different ways an app can be displayed.

Currently, my main pages is a `LayoutAwarePage` so it has logic to handle different visual states. However, my question is more how to make my page render differently depending on its state.

I thought, initially, that you basically created a layout for each state that the application supports. But it seems like the `VisualStateManager` portion of the XAML is just an area where you make piecemeal modifications to the design (hide an element, change an alignment).

I am working with a grid that has many columns and rows to organize my controls and it looks great in fullscreen. However, this doesn't work at all in the snapped state, as most of my controls become hidden off screen. I could certainly add a `ScrollViewer` control, but this is basically a hack and a usability nightmare for a user.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Typically you will have an entirely separate layout for snapped and fullscreen states.

Comment: Use the visual state manager to show/hide various parts of your UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your app doesn't lend itself to snapped view.  You are allowed to simply display a message / image that states this.  Alternatively, consider just showing the columns that are most important.

The standard MS way seems to be to replace horizontal oriented controls with vertical ones - maybe a listview or something would look better.  You'll probably find your code easier to read if you have one control for snapped and another for full screen.

Not exactly related to your question, but Blend works very well with XAML to allow you to manipulate the grid or show the relevant control.

Comment: To expound a bit for anyone in the future: The VisualStateManager is how you change your layout between view states (filled, snapped, etc.). However, you mostly just have your original view to work with. Sure, you can get more complicated with your animation, but it's meant to do stuff just like @pm_2 said: modify properties and change horizontal-oriented controls to a more vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good guide from Jerry Nixon.

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/12/walkthrough-implementing-snapview-in.html